# Div with a gradient? Placement possibilities

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm wondering if there was I could have done this a better way...check out this test link:  [link to developer site](http://www.amystout.com/germanmagic/clinics.html)

I made the black gradient box on the image (I cheated) was there a way I could have done this with css?  Like could I have made a div with a gradient that was somehow pushed down to the bottom of the image, yet still have my text show up in there the way it is?  Would be great because then I could change up the gradient box or even remove it without changing the picture...?

Here is the code for the containing the block

```
<div class="full-width-image-2 img-responsive">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="clinic-tagline"> learn, practice & have fun at a clinic
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Css:

```
.full-width-image-2 {
    background:url("../img/clinic-collage2.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height:400px;
    margin-top:140px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a linear gradient as a background with suitable color stops.

```css
body {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-3.jpg);
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-size:cover;
}
div {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100% );
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae nostrum tempora saepe blanditiis consectetur dolor qui animi. Dolor voluptatibus aliquid deserunt delectus asperiores laudantium impedit quisquam molestiae perferendis qui tenetur quia facilis numquam necessitatibus cumque laboriosam maxime. Debitis placeat nisi quaerat molestiae vel deserunt corporis. Mollitia officiis amet beatae maxime?</p></div>
```

Then it's just a matter of laying out the div as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :after pseudo element to add the text with an opaque background color.  Just absolute position the :after element relative to the div with the background image.

Simple example:
http://jsfiddle.net/j3epatxw/

HTML:

```
<div id="image-background">
    <p>This is the div w/ background image</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#image-background {
    height: 300px;
    background: #892242;
    position: relative;
    color: #ccc;
    /* add your background image here - just used a bg color to save time */
}

#image-background:after {
    content: 'learn, practice & have fun at a clinic';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU EVERYONE!  This is how I solved it:

```
 <div class="full-width-image-3 img-responsive"></div>

        <div class="gradient">

            <div class="clinic-tagline">learn, practice & have fun at a clinic</div>

        </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.clinic-tagline {
  margin-top: -180px;
  color: rgba(102, 101, 101, 0.87);
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-style:italic;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top:40px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  /* gradient:  */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.78) 32%, rgba(0,0,0,0.96) 98%, rgba(0,0,0,0.96) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(32%,rgba(0,0,0,0.78)), color-stop(98%,rgba(0,0,0,0.96)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.96))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.78) 32%,rgba(0,0,0,0.96) 98%,rgba(0,0,0,0.96) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.78) 32%,rgba(0,0,0,0.96) 98%,rgba(0,0,0,0.96) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.78) 32%,rgba(0,0,0,0.96) 98%,rgba(0,0,0,0.96) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.78) 32%,rgba(0,0,0,0.96) 98%,rgba(0,0,0,0.96) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#f5000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```